# What's the best way to record a voice and analyze the frequencies?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I need to convert voice samples and record them to the database. I am completely new to digital signal processing.

Ultimately, the goal is to find the outliers from the voice samples. But to do so, I need to obtain the frequencies and the hertz. But I do not know where to start.

FYI I have knowledge of most programming languages, Java, Python, Node, and Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to decompose a time series into its frequencies. As a starting point I'd suggest to read some documentation about the SciPy library, and in particular scipy.signal which is the signal processing toolbox within SciPy.

For a simple analysis of the frequencies of a signal, I like using the welch method, as explained here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html.
So, given a signal x with sampling rate Fs, you can obtain the power at each frequency bin using the pwelch method, like this (python 3x):

```
from scipy import signal
decomposed = signal.welch(x, fs = Fs) 

# Output is a tuple with frequency bins and the power at each bin
```

You should try playing with optional parameters, depending on the structure of your data and the desired resolution of the power spectral density. For instance:

```
decomposed = signal.welch(x, fs = Fs, nperseg = Fs*4, noverlap = Fs*2)
```